# Count the number of all nth children of all the root parent in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a collection from Laravel Eloquent query. Here grandfathers have many children(fathers), fathers have many children(grandchildren).
The returned result is this:

```
    [
  {
    "grand_father_id": "26",
    "fathers": [
      {
        "father_id": "101",
        "children": [
          {
            "child_id": "77",
            "children_weight": [
              {
                "weight": "30.00",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "child_id": "84",
            "children_weight": [
              {
                "weight": "20.00",
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "father_id": "102",
        "children": [
          {
            "child_id": "78",
            "children_weight": [
              {
                "weight": "50.00",
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "grand_father_id": "27",
    "fathers": [
      {
        "father_id": "100",
        "children": [
          {
            "child_id": "83",
            "children_weight": [
              {
                "weight": "100.00",
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "grand_father_id": "28",
    "fathers": [
      {
        "father_id": "105",
        "children": [
          {
            "child_id": "81",
            "children_weight": [
              {
                "weight": "80.00",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "child_id": "82",
            "children_weight": [
              {
                "weight": "0.00",
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "grand_father_id": "29",
    "fathers": [
      {
        "father_id": "108",
        "children": [
          {
            "child_id": "79",
            "children_weight": [
              {
                "weight": "44.00",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "child_id": "80",
            "children_weight": [
              {
                "weight": "56.00",
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "grand_father_id": "30",
    "fathers": [
      {
        "father_id": "107",
        "children": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How do I count the total number of all grandchildren of all grandfathers. I can ofcourse use nested loop to count this. But is there any other Laravel Collection method to do this? By the way, the example I gave here with grandfather, father, grandchildren is just an example with pseudo names. The real fields are `objectives`, `actions`, `success_indicators`, `success_indicator_weight`. The query to obtain the collection is:

```
return Objective::with([
        'actions' => function($query) {
        $query->select(['action_id', 'action_description', 'objective_id_fk']);
    }, 'actions.successIndicators' => function($query) {
        $query->select('success_indicator_id', 'success_indicator_description', 'action_id_fk');
    }, 'actions.successIndicators.SuccessIndicatorYearWeight' => function($query) {
        $query->select('success_indicator_weight', 'success_indicator_unit', 'success_indicator_id_fk');
    },
])->get()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a load of array_* helper methods for doing a variety of operations on nested arrays but I don't think there is anything that would serve your cause there. You can check for yourself - http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#arrays

I don't know myself if there is anything built into Collection but you could consider an accessor method of each Grandfather class:

```
class Grandfather extends Eloquent
{
    ...
    public function getTotalGrandchildrenAttribute()
    {
        $total_grandchildren = 0;
        // loop through each father
        foreach ($this->fathers as $father) {
            $total_grandchildren += count($father->children);
        }
        return $total_grandchildren;
    }
}
```

Then in your script:

```
$grandfathers = Grandfathers::all();

$total_grandchildren = 0;
foreach ($grandfathers as $grandfather) {
    $total_grandchildren += $grandfather->total_grandchildren;
}

echo "Total grandchildren: $total_grandchildren";
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

In addition, instead of using all() as shown above, you may want to use `with('fathers')` and `with('children')` so you're not hitting the DB every time you want to fetch fathers/ children:

```
$grandfathers = Grandfathers::with(array('fathers' => function($query) {
    $query->with('children');
});
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading